# Enable/disable a GameObject component from a script [Unity3D]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to take the value of a boolean (put in a variable called "bouclier") set in one script to enable or disable a GameObject.

The variable is in game object Player (bottom right here):

[image]

And I need to enable of disable this game object ("Bouclier01"):

[image]

To do this, I attached a script to game object "Bouclier01". Here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShowBouclier : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Bouclier01;
    public bool bouclier;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Bouclier01 = Bouclier01.GetComponent<GameObject>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Bouclier01.enabled = false;
        if (bouclier == true) {
            Bouclier01.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I must be missing something, because this comes up with this error message:

[image]

Any idea how to properly accomplish this?

Comment: enabled/disabled is for components

Comment: You should look up answers before asking them. This question was asked and answered countless times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use GameObject.SetActive() function to activate or deactivate a GameObject (I think GameObject.enabled was in the old API):

```
Bouclier.SetActive(false);
```

By the way, if you want to know the current activation state of a GameObject, use GameObject.activeSelf, which is a read only variable:

```
Debug.Log(Bouclier.activeSelf);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's one thing that was wrong, but I think there is more... I can't seem to be able to read the value of "bouclier" at the Player level. Is there something else obviously wrong in my script?

Comment: What happens with you exactly, can you talk more?

Comment: I'm making a little video to explain what's up, it will be up in a minute or two :)

Comment: Here's the vidéo! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0dAZw52Hlk
Should I ask another question?

Comment: I see that you are changing the variable `bouclier` in the script Move, but what about the variable `bouclier` in ShowBouclier  script, is there any relation between the two? I think you should change ShowBouclier.bouclier not Move.bouclier .

Answer (score 1):

> **it will works**

```
public GameObject otherobj;//your other object
public string scr;// your secound script name
void Start () {
(otherobj. GetComponent(scr) as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;
}
```