# Unity enable/disable component script from component on same gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

#### Preamble

I am currently making a game where a player can go from third person view, walking around to transition into a vehicle.

I have thought about using a transmitter/receiver type set up, but I think my way of simplifying it isn't correct.

I am using assets from third parties for controllers that use inputs.  My plan was to enable/disable the appropriate script and camera from the object I want to control.  I've gotten as far as being able to disable the previous controller and enable the next, though I can't go back to enabling since the script obviously doesn't run anymore.

#### Question/Request

I'd like to be able to reference the pawn's input component script in a different component script on the same gameobject to then be able to enable/disable the aformentioned component, though the issue is that the input controllers have variable names (Different names depending on the third party on each pawn).

Here's how I have it set up:
I have a `PlayerTransmitter` that handles the basics of turning things on and off.  I tried making this where all of the inputs are being handled, but I don't want to have to change the original controller scripts to look at this script. This is on an empty game object and handles the 'state' of the player, (walking or in which vehicle).

[image]

on each pawn gameobject (The walking pawn `CleanerPawn` and the vehicle `TractorPawn`), I've added a script called `InputReceiver`.  This was originally intended to pass the inputs from the `PlayerTransmitter` to the actual controller on the object itself.

Right now, the walking pawn has a component called `AdvancedWalkerController` (You may know the one I'm talking about) that controls the player walking movement and the vehicle has a component called `VehicleController` which controls how the vehicle moves and handles.

`CleanerPawn`

[image]

`TractorPawn`

[image]

The two images above show that I am using the same `InputReceiver` component on both pawns.  My plan was to pass in each pawn's input controller (temporarily named `CleanerController`) and then enable/disable that input controller depending on the `PlayerTransmitter` 'state'.

The `InputReceiver` currently looks like this:

```
    public bool isEnabled;
    public Component CleanerController;

    public void TurnOffControls()
    {
        isEnabled = false;
    }

    public void TurnOnControls()
    {
        isEnabled = true;
    }
```

In each pawn's input controller, I added a line to the `Update()` function:
`enabled = gameObject.GetComponent<InputReceiver>().isEnabled;`.  Two problems with this; 1.  I don't want to change any code in the input scripts (I hope this is possible) and 2. Once it's disabled, it won't read an update to enable itself again.

I was hoping I could just use the reference to the component `CleanerController` to say `CleanerController.enabled = true; or false` with that reference being just that one component, though I'm missing something here.

My final thought which I am going to try is to allow/disallow the input controls within each input script depending on my `isEnabled` boolean.  Though again, I would have to change the original scripts to accommodate this.

Comment: hi, not sure if this might be of interest  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238795/enable-disable-a-gameobject-component-from-a-script-unity3d

Comment: @jspcal, Thank you for sharing.  That particular question/answer is turning off the entire GameObject where I am just trying to disable a single component on the game object.  If I am missing something, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What speaks against

```
public Behaviour CleanerController;
```

and then

```
CleanerController.enabled = false; // or true accordingly
```

See

- [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html)

  > Behaviours are Components that can be enabled or disabled.
- [`Behaviour.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)

  > Enabled Behaviours are Updated, disabled Behaviours are not.

  or in other words: If a `Behaviour` is set to `enabled = false` then it's `Update` (and similar event methods) is not called anymore.

Comment: I was totally missing `Behaviour`, This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a Controller Script. This named "CameraController" for example and has a Method to switch between the Modes. This would also make it possible to have even more Options. For Example you could use an Enum to define which modes exist:

```cs
enum CameraMode {
    Player,
    Car
}

public SwitchMode(CameraMode mode) {
    switch(mode) {
        case CameraMode.Player:
            TurnOnControls();
            break;
        case CameraMode.Car:
            TurnOffControls();
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You could even go further and create an Interface/Abstract which allows all of this and just has an execute method doing different stuff. In the end you just need that controller which allowes to swtich between the modes and handles the key input.

Comment: Thank you for the response, though I'm able to turn the cameras on and off, but the main question was about turning on/off the specific component script instead.  I'm going to edit my question to remove my confusing parts.

Comment: Oh I missread that. But It realy does not matter if its the cam or the script. You can use the controller script to turn on/off other scripts as well without any struggle.